# Can't retrieve file content via download URL

Tags: google-drive-api

Since about an hour, I can't retrieve file content via the download URL attribute.

Each time I try to get it, API answers a 401 (unauthorized error).

Here's the code used: https://gist.github.com/arnaudbreton/5409015
Credentials are stored in GAE datastore and successfully retrieved / refresh.
The first call to file endpoint is working but not the second call to download content.

It was working this morning.
I tried different things so far:
- Revoke client secret (found as a solution in an other thread)
- Create a new client to test
- Disconnect my APP from Drive, accept it again

Nothing seems to solve my issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We're aware of the issue and looking in to it. Primarily affects apps using the drive.file scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix/rollback is in progress, should be back to normal soon.

Comment: sir, while sharing file using Gapi SDk, origin must not be the localhost ?- @steve Bazyl

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
resp.alternateLink;
resp.webContentLink;
```

i got stucked in the same issue a day back , using downloadUrl to get the content but got it with webContentLink.

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list();
                request.execute(function (resp) {

resp.alternateLink;
    resp.webContentLink;
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But as @Steve Bazyl said  fix/rollback is in progress.