# Google Drive (401) Not Authorized Error

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been using a Google Drive SDK integration since October.  It has worked fine since then, and I have not modified the code in the project since I got it working.  Today, for some unknown reason, every request to download or upload a file to the drive returns an error:

The remote server returned an error (401) not authorized.

The section of code I am currently working on is:

```
    public static Stream GetDownloadStream(string id)
    {
        File file = DriveService.Files.Get(id).Fetch();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.DownloadUrl))
        {
            Stream stream;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(
                new Uri(file.DownloadUrl));
            Auth.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);
            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.StatusDescription);
                }
                return stream;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                GetCredentials();
                return GetDownloadStream(id);
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("File Cannot Be Downloaded.");
    }
```

The error is returned at the request.GetResponse() method call.  The DriveService properly loads the file, and the file has what appears to be a properly formed DownloadURL.  Everything about the DriveService seems to work in the rest of the code, it searches and retrieves file info properly, but for some reason, it won't download or upload.  Has there been some change to the format of the DownloadURL at the google server end that I need to incorporate into my code?

Comment: What's your client library's version?

Comment: I believe the underlying issue has been fixed, please confirm that this was the same issue you were having. Thanks

Comment: There was a known problem, a similar thread is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072758/cant-retrieve-file-content-via-download-url

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I noticed the other thread after I posted this question, and so I slept on it.  When I woke up this morning, my code worked fine again.  It looks like it was probably just something server side at google?

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled web security? It seems google drive is checking that one.

--disable-web-security

If so, enable web security. It worked for me.

Comment: Yes I have also found this in general use of Google Drive in Google Chome. With "--disable-web-security" flag enabled it won't load the "apps" associated with my Drive account.  Removing that flag allows Drive to function normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Some time downloadurl  is expired so that  time create new request and download file again.
also because of incorrect refresh token and access token.