# Retrieving Google Doc with Drive API has stopped working

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api

This seems to be a recurrence of this problem: 
[Can't retrieve file content via download URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072758/cant-retrieve-file-content-via-download-url).

In particular, downloading a Google Doc file using exportLinks gives 401 (Unauthorized).  The same problem has also been reported [here](https://plus.google.com/106635773276154443261/posts/XTn74FysTLg).

This was working fine a few days ago with 'drive.file' scope, now only works with 'drive' scope (but this isn't an acceptable solution since app shouldn't be able to get access to all of a user's files, only those it has created).

Thanks

Comment: We fixed the issue, but changes aren't deployed yet. It will be fixed very soon, sorry.

Comment: Excellent stuff! Many thanks Burcu